# Qt modify PathItem

Tags: c++, qt, operators, qgraphicsitem

is there a way to modify the path of QGraphicsPathItem in Qt?

I created the Item this way:

```
    QGraphicsPathItem* item = new QGraphicsPathItem();
    QPainterPath* path = new QPainterPath();
    path->cubicTo(3,5, 3,10, 0,15);
    item->setPath(*path);
    item->moveBy(-20,-20);
    scene->addItem(item);
```

now i want to modify the elements of the path:

```
    item->path().elementAt(0).y = -5;
    item->path().elementAt(0).x =  0;
```

but i get following error:

```
assignment of member 'QPainterPath::Element::y' in read-only object
```

Answer (score 0):

Since path() returns a QPainterPath, you will need to modify the path with:

```
void QPainterPath::setElementPositionAt(int index, qreal x, qreal y)
```

and then re-set the path to the QGraphicsPathItem.

Here is a sample:

```
QPainterPath p = item->path();
p.setElementPositionAt(0, 0, -5);
item->setPath(p);
```

It would be wise to also use:

path->elementCount()

to ensure the index you are wanting to modify is within bounds.